# WordPress CPT archive page display sticky post first and then display the rest of the posts in same Query

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

I'm having one Custom post type I have added a Sticky Option to that Custom Post Type. When I choose the post as sticky means it's not working for me.

I have tried the below code.

Please don't add this as a duplicate question, Here I can see a solution for this but they are having two queries passing I need this in one query. I don't need to pass two different queries. I need that in the same query.

Thanks in advance.

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

$query_args = [
    'post_type'           => $this->post_type,
    'post_status'         => 'publish',
    'orderby'             => 'post__in',
    'tax_query'           => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'post_type'     => $this->post_type,
            'post__in'      => $sticky,
        ),
        array(
            'post_type'     => $this->post_type,
            'post__not_in'  => $sticky,
        )
    ],
];
```

Comment: is that a CPT archive, or is it a page with a custom template that uses queries to pretend it's a CPT archive? I ask because the main query is meant to do this automatically via the built in sticky posts functionality in WordPress, but I can't tell if you're using `$query_args` to replace/modify the main query to show something different or because the main query is for a page that you've used a page builder or custom template on. Also why are you using `tax_query` to query sticky posts? Are the two clauses not paradoxical? (a post cannot be in stick and not in sticky at the same time )

Comment: can you also expand on "I have added a Sticky Option to that Custom Post Type", what did you do to add the sticky option?

Comment: I'm new to WordPress. Can you help me to fix this one? @TomJNowell

Comment: how did you create the code in your question? Can you edit your question to answer as many of the questions I asked? Even if the answer is that you don't know that's still useful for people answering to know, even the most basic info would be helpful, including which file that code is from as well as what comes directly after it. Use the edit link to update the question